# Why won't my top level react-native component expand to the full dimensions?

Tags: react-native, next.js, react-native-paper

I'm using `next.js` if that matters and my `pages/_app.tsx` has:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

    return (
        <PaperProvider theme={customTheme}>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, top: 0, left: 0, height: '100%', width: '100%', zIndex: 10, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                <Text> Here</Text>
            </View>
        </PaperProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

and `customTheme` is:

```
import { DefaultTheme } from 'react-native-paper';

export const customTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        primary: '#247BA0',
        accent: '#70C1B3',
        error: '#FF1654',
        disabled: '#F3FFBD',
        placeholder: '#D3EDBE',
    }
}
```

I see `Text`, but no red background. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have any idea about `react-native-paper` but if I could try something I would add `style={{ flex: 1 }}` to `PaperProvider`

Comment: Can't add `style` to `PaperProvider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem here is the use of `position: 'absolute'` with `height: '100%'`, delete one of these properties in your style object and it should work.
If you want the full screen to have background color change `height: '100%'` to `height: Dimensions.get("window").height`